# callback function issues Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
function addToServer(myid) {
    console.log("jayesh"+db.server.find({id:myid})+"\n");
    return db.server.find({id:myid});
};
addToServer(myid,function(resp) {
    console.log("something");
    if(resp.count()>0)
        console.log("present");
    else
        console.log("Nope");
});
```

I want to know whether document with id = myid is present in server collection. I guess there is some issue with callback but being a novice don't have much a knowledge about it. Please help me out.Thanks

P.S For function I am getting output saying "jayesh[object Object] "
     and nothing is printing for callback method.

Comment: Well, that `db.find` call is async, so you have to wait for an answer (callback) -- and go from there.

Comment: Where is your callback being executed in addToServer()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you trying to write synchronous code inside an asynchronous environment.

#### You need to pass callbacks:

```
function addToServer(myid, cb) {
    db.server.find({id:myid},cb);
};

addToServer(myid,function(err, resp) {
    if(err) {
      console.log("err");
    } else if(resp.count()>0) {
      console.log("present");
    } else {
      console.log("Nope");
    }
});
```

In async programming you cannot **throw** and cannot **return** you use **callbacks** instead!

These callbacks are **conventionally** invoked with an error object (alternative to `throw`) as the first argument and all other arguments with the returned data (alternative to `return`).

[Reading Material on Async Programming Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355240/reading-material-on-async-programming-practices)